# Plant identification: Small Pink flower on evergreen plant ~2"x2"x2"

Tags: identification, flowers

Need help with identifying this plant:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be Argyranthemum frutescens, a pink variety, often commonly known as pink marguerite daisy. There are various pink named varieties - it is not hardy below USDA zone 10, but is actually a small, perennial shrub. Yours looks like it needs cutting back because its quite woody at the base, but this should not be done till spring, and don't cut back too far into the old wood, it may not recover, though usually,these are pretty good at regenerating from older wood. If you want to cut back quite a bit,cut back to where you can see a leaf or growth bud on that old wood. http://www.learn2grow.com/plants/argyranthemum-frutescens-argymip-molimba-pink-molimba-series-ppaf/